# Xamarin.Forms Push Notification Payload in Android

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Hi I have a push notification handler in my Android project. My goal is to have a different payload for each notification.

The problem is when I received notifications
[image]
and tap on a notification I want, the payload I get is usually the very first notification arrived. So for example from my screenshot, I tapped on notification with **qHzkeyRp~~~~~: 2** I get the payload from **Jayson Pogi: 1** notification. Other scenario is when I tapped on the first notification arrived, other notifications doesn't have payload.

Here's my code just incase

```
public void CreateLocalNotificaiton(string title, string body, string payload, int notifId, string groupName, bool hasIntent = false)
{
    //var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, AppConstants.NotificationChannelName)
    //    .SetContentTitle(title)
    //    .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.appicon)
    //    .SetContentText(body)
    //    .SetPriority(1)
    //    .SetVisibility((int)NotificationVisibility.Public)
    //    .SetChannelId(AppConstants.NotificationChannelId)
    //    .SetAutoCancel(true)
    //    .SetGroup("com.pordiva.omnigoo.businessmobile.OmniGoo")
    //    .SetShowWhen(false)
    //    ;
    var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, AppConstants.NotificationChannelName)
        .SetContentTitle(title)
        .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.appicon)
        .SetContentText(body)
        .SetPriority(PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
        .SetChannelId(AppConstants.NotificationChannelId)
        .SetAutoCancel(true)
        //.SetGroupSummary(true)
        //.SetGroup("com.pordiva.omnigoo.businessmobile." + groupName)
        ;

    if (hasIntent)
    {
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask | ActivityFlags.SingleTop);

        // add extra data so we can retreive this 
        if (payload != null)
        {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.PutString("payload", payload);
            intent.PutExtras(bundle);
        }

        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(
            this,
            0,
            intent,
            PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

        notificationBuilder.SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    }

    var notificationManager = GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager; // NotificationManager.FromContext(CrossCurrentActivity.Current.AppContext);

    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
    {
        NotificationImportance importance = global::Android.App.NotificationImportance.High;

        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(AppConstants.NotificationChannelId, title, importance);
        notificationChannel.EnableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.EnableVibration(true);
        notificationChannel.SetShowBadge(true);
        notificationChannel.Importance = NotificationImportance.High;
        notificationChannel.SetVibrationPattern(new long[] { 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400 });

        if (notificationManager != null)
        {
            notificationBuilder.SetChannelId(AppConstants.NotificationChannelId);
            notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }
    }


    notificationManager.Notify(notifId, notificationBuilder.Build());
}
```

---

SOLVED
Must have unique value in PendingIntent.GetActivity requestCode parameter

Comment: It seems that you have solved your problem now, please give one reply for your thread and mark your reply as answer, it is beneficial to others who face the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Must have unique value in `PendingIntent.GetActivity` `requestCode` parameter